# How to fix Error : ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/crt1.o: No such file or directory

Tags: linker, fortran

I was trying to compile my fortran code
following error generated

```
sfanwer@genesis ~/WORK/NNF/anwar/re40_n1 $ ifort new_nnfsossip.for -o new.x


ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/crti.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find -lm
ld: cannot find -lpthread
ld: cannot find -lc
ld: cannot find -ldl
ld: cannot find -lc
ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/crtn.o: No such file or directory
```

i tried to check whether ifort is installed or not

```
sfanwer@genesis ~/WORK/NNF/anwar/re40_n1 $ ifort -v
ifort version 15.0.3
```

Hence it is installed

Answer (score 0):

Your IntelFortran Compiler is installed but you need to link the library.You should check the help for ld command.

```
ld --help
```

For example

```
 ifort -o fcode fcode.f -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -lblas
```

You must install LAPACK and  BLAS on local systems.Also you should try to write a simple makefile.

Comment: how can i do so? sorry for bothering with such a simple one .. i am new o this .. do i need to setup environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method could solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```